# It does not pass from Web UI to Select Version

Tags: ambari

[image]

I can not proceed to the next state.

```
/var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.log
INFO [ambari-client-thread-37] AmbariMetaInfo:1430 - Stack HDP-2.0.6 is not active, skipping VDF
INFO [ambari-client-thread-37] AmbariMetaInfo:1430 - Stack HDP-2.0.6 is not active, skipping VDF
INFO [ambari-client-thread-37] AmbariMetaInfo:1430 - Stack HDP-2.0.6.GlusterFS is not active, skipping VDF
INFO [ambari-client-thread-37] AmbariMetaInfo:1430 - Stack HDP-2.1 is not active, skipping VDF
INFO [ambari-client-thread-37] AmbariMetaInfo:1430 - Stack HDP-2.1.GlusterFS is not active, skipping VDF
INFO [ambari-client-thread-37] AmbariMetaInfo:1428 - Stack HDP-2.3.GlusterFS is not valid, skipping VDF: The service 'OOZIE' in stack 'HDP:2.3.GlusterFS' extends a non-existent service: 'common-services/OOZIE/5.0.0.2.3'
...
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you follow the installation steps ? https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.2.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/hdp_start_the_ambari_server.html Could you please update with more details

Comment: I followed this steps. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.3 And I used a remote database(postgresql).

Comment: Is there any ERROR in the log ?

Comment: Is this similar to your issue ? https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/142793/add-node-to-the-ambari-cluster-the-next-button-not.html

Comment: There is no error in ambari-server.log. And When I installed yum, it worked normally. But when I build from source, the above error appears.