# ambari 2.7.4 Installation Wizard problems

Tags: cluster-computing, ambari

Ambari built. Network on virtual machines set. Trying to install cluster with the installation wizard of ambari UI. Could not get passed from "Get Started" to "Select version".

There is this error in the logs:

```
Could not load repo results
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/HDP/hdp_urlinfo.json
```

[Found question with same problem which was not resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862180/it-does-not-pass-from-web-ui-to-select-version)

Screenshot from UI:
[image: Screenshot from UI]

Comment: Also, find the same error in logs of another version of ambari but it works. So problem not in this error.

Answer (score 0):

@eGs

It looks like you missed some steps and prerequisites before installing ambari.  127.0.0.1 should not be used to access the UI.   Ambari docs require use to use FQDNs for all nodes and hosts.

Additionally, the 403 error above is result from using versions of ambari/hdp which cloudera has moved behind a paywall.   User/password is required to access these assets now.

You should try with Ambari 2.7.4 and repos and artifacts that are not behind a paywall.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can access UI with the host of my master, and with localhost on my master, get the same.

Comment: The URL of the Ambari Server UI can be any address... If it cannot be `localhost`, then that would mean its just being installed and started as a process on a remote machine. When clients are added, the server address doesn't come from the browser URL